# Is it correct to do SVD from the latent space of an autoencoder?

Tags: pca, autoencoders, svd, manifold-learning

Is it correct to do SVD from the latent space of an autoencoder?

I am asking because I think that by performing SVD from a latent space, and plotting the singular values, it is possible to know the dimension of the data.

Example: let's say that we have a reaction-diffusion system which is a one-dimensional manifold. The system is embedded in a large state space (100 x100 =10^4). If we do dimension reduction with an autoencoder up to 10, and we perform SVD in that latent representation, there will be only one single value which will dominate the other nine.